# Callback parameter messing up ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get data through an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1048",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.item.name);

    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }

});
```

Because it's a third party api, I just jsonp. The problem is: I get an syntax error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :".

When I look in the console, I see the data but it keeps saying Unexpected token :, so I can't see the data

Now when I click and navigate to that url, I can view the data (so the runescape url)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you still get the error if you put console.log in comments?

Comment: yes, doesn't change anything

Comment: You say "when I look in the console, I see the data" so it sounds as if your function is actually working fine... could the error be some other code you're trying to run immediately after this?

Comment: @Andreas the server is returning me 404

Comment: @DougMcLean: I suspect he/she means the Network tab, not the `console.log` output.

Comment: @DougMcLean i see the data when i click on the error message-url, it opens in the tab "sources" in the developer section

Answer (score 3):

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :".

Sounds like the third-party API doesn't support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), since that's the error when you try to treat JSON as though it were JSONP. Remember that JSONP requires that **both ends** cooperate.

Look at the documentation for the API in question, it may not support JSONP, may support it through a different endpoint, may require a parameter telling it that you want JSONP (though usually they just look for the `callback` request parameter that jQuery will automatically add), etc.

Just for completeness: The reason that the server side needs to know what's going on is that it needs to send back a different response. Here's an example JSON response:

```
{"someProperty":"someValue"}
```

Here's the JSONP version of that:

```
someFunctionName({"someProperty":"someValue"})
```

...where `someFunctionName` is defined by the *caller*, via a request parameter. The server has to look for the parameter and use it when generating the response. This is because JSONP is not ajax, strictly speaking, which is why it's not subject to the SOP that normally rules ajax calls.

Comment: Agreed - if you go to http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1048 in a browser you get a JSON, not JSONP response, and the same happens even if you include a callback e.g. http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1048&callback=test

Comment: When I try to use normal json in the ajax call, with url being a php script that uses file_get_contents of the runescape url, it takes more than 30 seconds to load, how can I resolve that?

Comment: @Eselko: That's an unrelated question. I suggest posting it as a question with the `php` tag and other relevant ones.